# Using ogrinfo in Python to find specified information

Tags: python, shapefile, ogrinfo

I am using ogrinfo in Python to find out information about a shapefile

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


args = ['ogrinfo', '-so', '-al', 'C:/test/test_shapefile.shp']
process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

stdout = process.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip()
print(stdout)
```

This obviously gives me a large summary, but I'm wondering is there any way to specify that I only want information regarding the `extents` or `EPSG` for example?

Comment: Please don't repost closed Questions, especially with less information than the original  [Save certain ogrinfo results to variable in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429693/save-certain-ogrinfo-results-to-variable-in-python)

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use the `subprocess` module? if not, there is a charming [`PyShp`](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) package for that. Also pay attention to this thread : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113799/reading-shapefile-in-python

Comment: @Taras no it's not mandatory, it is just one of the first snippets of code I got working. I'll definitely look into PyShp - thank you!

Comment: GDAL is also a Python module, you can get file informations : https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-shapefile-feature-count

Comment: ogrinfo is a part of GDAL :)

Comment: Yes, I perfectly know, but it's also a Python module, so you can call it as `from osgeo import gdal` instead of call a `subprocess`.